# Approximation to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{x}n^k$ with integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, summation

Taking a quick look at a graph, it should be fairly obvious that $$\int_0^xn^kdn<\sum_{n=0}^xn^k<\int_0^{x+1}n^kdn$$

If $k>1$ and $x=1,2,3,\dots$

I was wondering if there existed tighter bounds and if there could be any good analytic continuation/integral form for $\sum_{n=0}^xn^k$.

Comment: Lookup finite/discrete calculus. If $n^k$ can be expressed in terms of falling powers then something analogous to the exponent rule can be used to get an exact solution.

Comment: @1110101001 Could you perhaps put this into a question?

Comment: There are very good approximations of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{x}n^k$ using the properties of harmonic numbers. Involving integrals, I really don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the first step
towards deriving the
Euler-Maclaurin formula,
which expresses the
sum of a function
in terms of the
function's integral,
value, and derivatives.

Look here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

Comment: Good answer (+1).  Though I still wonder if I can improve my original integral, which seems messy by your link.